# Visual Studio 2015 C# XAML Designer doesn't load

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In the new Visual Studio 2015 RC the XAML designer does not bring up a UI for a C# Windows Universal project but it does for a C++ Windows Universal project.  This occurs with both the Professional and Community editions.  Has any one experience the same problem and have a workaround/solution?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is the visual designer just hidden because the text designer is full view (tab at the bottom of the screen that says "Design")?

Comment: Good suggestion, I looked for that but the Design tab doesn't even show up.

Comment: I had the same issue.  I'm currently reinstalling from scratch to see if maybe it was a glitch.

Comment: I suspect this might be because I am on a Windows 8.1 system and not a Windows 10 system.  I was able to create a Windows 8.1 Universal app using C# and the XAML designer loaded as expected.

Comment: Same problem here, using Windows 8.1 as well. Guess that's the trigger then.

Comment: Verified that when Visual Studio 2015 Community is Installed on Windows 10 the XAML designer does show up for a C# Universal App.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To help clarify this a bit -

If you are building a Universal Windows 10 application with Visual Studio 2015 running on Windows 8.1 - something that we have enabled for the first time without requiring your to upgrade your OS, you will not be offered the XAML designer option - we will only allow you to edit XAML using the editor and IntelliSense. Similarly, you will not be allowed to test the application locally or using the Simulator (since it is a Windows 10 application and cannot run on your machine). Everything else should work fine, but for the best experience possible, consider upgrading to Windows 10.

If you are building a Windows 8.1 universal application, it should work just like before.

Comment: Same problem but I'm on windows 10

Comment: Well, you will be offered the XAML designer option (e.g. in context menu), but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 49):

I have the same issue, when I upgraded the Win10 SDK from 10240 to 10586, set the project properties->Application->Target version to Windows 10(10.0;Build 10240), 
the design view shows up again.

[image: screenshot of the setting to change]

Comment: This solved the issue for me. It seems to be a bug with the build targets for Windows 10 Build 10586. Setting the target version to 10240 made the designer show up again.

Comment: This worked for me as well.. cmon microsoft get your stuff together!!

Comment: It is for sure the answer as it solved the issue for me as well although it wasn't as easy as stated here. I added an updated answer.

Answer (score 16):

If the XAML designer is failing to open, check the "Flag" notifications in the top right corner. You might notice a message that your Windows 10 build needs to be updated.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZKWH.png): [image]

The target platform can't be newer than the Windows 10 build you're actually running.

Comment: Indeed I just had this message. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 (fresh install + Developer mode)
VS 2015 Update 1 Ultimate
SDK Build 10586
By default no designer being available even via Shift-F7.

This expands the scope of the original problem, its not a VS edition based issue at all. Its a problem with the SDK support.

AS per Wener Henze

Swtich back to Build 10240.
Fixed. Designer now available.

Werners workaround is confirmed and saved me lots of time. I don't have the rep to thank him, or comment on his post directly.

Answer (score 3):

I installed fresh Windows 10 and Visual Studio Community 2015, and the designer failed to load (for MainPage.xaml etc). I had to:

1. enable developer mode in system settings (update section) as suggested in info dialog
2. (re)install Visual C++ redistributable for VS 2015

But I don't know which one exactly resolved the problem... Now the designer loads as expected. (I tried only C# universal app yet)

Comment: I wanted to comment also as this has plagued me.  I had developer mode enabled and it didn't fix it.  However, I went *back* into developer mode (which was already selected) and then a message appeared below it that it was updating features.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have installed fresh Windows 10 Build 10240 and downloaded and installed latest Visual Studio 2015, target version 10240 is not available in Project Properties -> Application -> Target version and designer is not working too.

I have got Target version 10240 selection available after I've installed additionally Windows 10 RTM SDK from following [page](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/sdk-archive). As discussed above, designer works fine if Target version 10240 is selected.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the answer of @Ivan because I just had to do with this issue recently.

[image: Application]

In my case I only had the option to change the Min Version from 10586 to 10240 but for the Target version I had no other choice than 10586. So solving this issue was not possible.

The solution was to install SDK Version 1506 (Version 10.0.26624.0) which can be found here https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

After a restart of Visual Studio I was able to switch the Target version as well @Ivan mentioned and the XAML designer finally showed up. Heureka!

Thanks for the hint @Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have the appropriate sdk installed on your machine, you can get it from the official site of Microsoft https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

before that please remove the old sdk you installed on your pc, so that VS will use the new one.

then it'll work... i fixed mine in this way.